# Convert a set of strings into a simple string c++

Tags: c++, string, set

I have a set of strings, `set<string> aSet`. How to convert the set to just a single string and have all the elements separated by a comma?

Comment: concatenate the strings and the commas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
std::copy(aSet.begin(), aSet.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(stream, ","));
std::string result = stream.str();
```

Comment: This will have a trailing comma at the end

Answer (score 6):

Here's the simple and readable way without anything fancy:

```
string s;

for (auto const& e : aSet)
{
    s += e;
    s += ',';
}

s.pop_back();
```

Comment: Yeah, profile it as always, and if it proves inefficient: optimize. Readability first.

Comment: The C++ compiler might be able to optimize the `O(n2)` inherent complexity of this method, but I doubt it very much.

Comment: @chqrlie Inefficient how?  In my quick tests (concatenating 2000 strings), this version is up to 50 times faster than the std::accumulate answer above, and four times faster than the accepted answer.

Comment: @James: I guess the `std::string` implementation handles repeated concatenations gracefully, probably by reallocating the backstore with a geometrically increasing length. It might also be a side effect of the heap allocation strategy where block sizes happen to grow geometrically too, at least up to the length of your set of strings. You might experience performance degradation for really large sets (millions on strings). A more conservative approach would measure the length of the resulting set and allocate it in 1 call. This requires 2 loops. You could benchmark that too.

Comment: @James: regarding the comparison with Slava's answer, I am glad an elegant loop beats a klutzy one-liner with a lambda function. The core if the explanation is `s += e; s+= ',';` is more efficient than `r = a + ',' + b;`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yeah, preallocating is always going to be faster.  I did the same in Oso XML Merge many years ago and gained a huge performance increase for certain operations.  I suspect the biggest problem with the std::accumulate method is just the sheer number of temporary strings involved.

Comment: preallocating the string is not faster: https://quick-bench.com/q/HcpI8Nrx5Ac6-d9y9n9tpOKGaUA

Answer (score 5):

[accumulate example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) has code to concatenate vector of ints to string, which can be easily converted for your purpose:

```
std::string s = std::accumulate( std::begin(aSet), 
                                 std::end(aSet), 
                                 std::string{},
                                 [](const std::string& a, const std::string &b ) {
                                    return a.empty() ? b
                                           : a + ',' + b; } );
```